# How to update nested JSON object fields in mongo Db collection using ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, nested-json

I have a JSON object(**Form**) in the mongo collection like this

```json
{
    "_id": "87124eb6-c9f7-49b9-8470-8c2b7fb07dc8",
    "VisitName": "demo visit",
    "Version": "string",
    "FormStatus": "string",
    "FormName": "demo form",
    "IsDeleted": false,
    "Pages": [
        {
            "PageName": "demo page",
            "PageNo": 1,
            "PageStatus": true,
            "Field": [
                {
                    "FieldName": "Gender",
                    "Value": "demo value",
                    "Comment": "demo comment",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to edit the **Field** (which is an array of objects ).
Currently, I am loading the full **form** and replacing the **field** data to be updated, Then replace the new form with the old one.

loading the whole **form** for each **field** update may affect performance, when loading large **forms**
Is there any way to update only the **field** details with *fieldName*(Unique) Instead of fetching the whole **Form** and editing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Update: I missed the ASP.NET tag before answering this. I hope, this still gets you to the solution

You can use an update with [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/). Here's a [playground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8blrXGiX882) to test it.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "FormName": "demo form"
},
{
  $set: {
    "Pages.$[pageItem].Field.$[fieldItem].Value": "new value"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "pageItem.PageName": "demo page"
    },
    {
      "fieldItem.FieldName": "Gender"
    }
  ]
})
```

Basically, you tell MongoDB, update the nested field in the corresponding array element, that fulfils the filter specified by `arrayFilters`. So in this case, you update the path: `"Pages.$[pageItem].Field.$[fieldItem].Value"` to the `new value` but only in those nested documents, that:

- reside in a page, whose name is `demo page`
- and, in that page, there is a filed, whose name is `Gender`